# install opencv 2.4.9 on ubuntu14.01 gave error

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu

I was following this tutorial

http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

and others tutorial looks similar and I had also tried

everything works fine before I typed

> **make**

and i got this error message  like this

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so', needed by`lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

and I also google for this error

but i could not match my problem :(

thank your helping

Comment: Why not install from the Ubuntu repositories?  You can just do `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`.

Comment: i have install libopencv-dev but how it work?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: ah  I want to use the face detection by opencv and clone this project https://github.com/bsdnoobz/web-based-face-detec

Comment: ok i have done
i just change the cmake parameter to cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after I install this package 
it works

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy python-tk libtbb-dev libeigen2-dev yasm libfaac-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev sphinx-common texlive-latex-extra libv4l-dev libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the libGL.so is usually a soft link and the origial .so file that libGL.so is linked to can not be found. You can find the original file e.g. libGL.so.1.0.0 under the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and link libGL.so to it.

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Note that libGL.so.x.x.x might be different according to different versions.